# Как в TeamCity в письме указать количество пройденных тестов?

Tags: teamcity

Например, мне нужно в письме, которое отправляется при завершении билда, добавить "Пройдено 90 из 100" тестов. Как нужно модифицировать шаблон? Или где можно посмотреть все переменные с описанием?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Учитывая, что не указана версия TeamCity и какой тестовый фреймворк используется, есть общее (не самое эффективное) решение.

[В официальной документации по настройке оповещений](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Customizing+Notifications) есть пример с фильтрацией сообщений build.log:

```
<#list build.buildLog.messages[1..] as message><#-- skipping the first message (it is a root node)-->
    <#if message.status == "ERROR" || message.status == "FAILURE" >
        ${message.text}
    </#if>
</#list>
```

Можно пройти по всем сообщениям и найти те, что тебя интересуют. Например, gtest++ выдаёт следующие строки:

> [11:43:01][Step 4/14] [==========] 322 tests from 66 test cases ran. (54674 ms total)
>   [11:43:01][Step 4/14] [  PASSED  ] 322 tests.

В той же [документации](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Customizing+Notifications) есть пример раздел **TeamCity Notification Properties** дающий подсказку, где искать список всех существующих **properties**:

> < TeamCity Data Directory >/config/internal.properties

Возможно, там ты найдешь что-то полезное.

Comment: TeamCity 2017.1.3
Тестовый фреймворк - xUnit + TOSCA (возвращает в формате Ant JUnit)
Спасибо! Я сейчас попробую.